How to Design a Spinnaker Pipeline for Blue-Green Deployment with Automated Active Production Detection?
I'm setting up a Blue-Green deployment strategy using Spinnaker for my Kubernetes-based application. The goal is to alternate between Blue and Green environments for each deployment. I need guidance on how to design a Spinnaker pipeline that can:

Deploy a new version to the non-active environment (Green if Blue is active, and vice versa).
Automatically switch traffic to the new environment.
Clean up the old environment after traffic is switched.
Detect the currently active production environment to decide the deployment target.

I am unsure how Spinnaker can determine whether the Blue or Green environment is currently active in this process.
I used the deploy type with rollout in Spinnaker, but it doesn't seem to handle the Blue <-> Green switch in the way I want.
